# Injecting custom datastax.session into Spring-Data Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, datastax, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

Is it possible to use a custom datastax session for Spring-Data?

Hi, I know Spring-Data for Cassandra uses datastax session internally. However I have a custom datastax session object (given by another service) that I would like Spring-Data to use instead of the one prewired. Assuming the versions of both datastax sessions are the same, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

Depending on your setup, there are a couple of approaches. Let me explain the two most common scenarios:

**Direct usage of Template API**

```
Session yourSession = …;

CqlTemplate cqlTemplate = new CqlTemplate(yourSession);

CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate = new CassandraTemplate(yourSession);
```

**Exposing the Session as `@Bean`**

This one might require a bit more setup as configuration support expects usage of `CassandraSessionFactoryBean` and `CassandraClusterFactoryBean`.

Take a look at [`AbstractCassandraConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/e6b5c5e7a2af5c020526e6d998d5950b74163937/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/config/AbstractCassandraConfiguration.java#L53) to see what supporting beans (`CassandraConverter`, `CassandraMappingContext`) are configured to configure Spring Data's Cassandra support.

```
@Configuration
class MyCassandraConfig {

    private final Session mySession;

    public MyCassandraConfig(Session mySession) {
        this.mySession = mySession;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraConverter cassandraConverter() {

        MappingCassandraConverter mappingCassandraConverter = new MappingCassandraConverter(cassandraMapping());

        mappingCassandraConverter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());

        return mappingCassandraConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() {

        Cluster cluster = mySession.getCluster();
        String keyspace = mySession.getLoggedKeyspace();

        CassandraMappingContext mappingContext = new CassandraMappingContext(
                new SimpleUserTypeResolver(cluster, keyspace), new SimpleTupleTypeFactory(cluster));

        CustomConversions customConversions = customConversions();

        mappingContext.setCustomConversions(customConversions);
        mappingContext.setSimpleTypeHolder(customConversions.getSimpleTypeHolder());

        return mappingContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new CassandraCustomConversions(Collections.emptyList());
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate() {
        return new CassandraTemplate(mySession, cassandraConverter());
    }
}
```